# curl with Variable not work - Shell Script

Tags: shell, curl, sh

when I execute a normal curl via a shell script functioniert es.

This work:

```
curl -s -v -X POST --data '{
    "zoneConfig": {
        "userID": "'$userid'",
        "name": "'$myName'",
        "id":"'$id'"
    },
    "delete": [
        {
            "id": "ID1"
        },
        {
            "id": "ID2"
        }
    ]
}' https://urlToAPI
```

But as soon as I put "delete" in a variable I get an undefined error from the API vendor

This is not working

```
delete='{
    "id": "ID1"
},
{
    "id": "ID2"
}'

curl -s -v -X POST --data '{
    "zoneConfig": {
        "userID": "'$userid'",
        "name": "'$myName'",
        "id":"'$id'"
    },
    "delete": [
        '$deleteValues'
    ]
}' https://urlToAPI
```

But I don't understand the difference as both configurations are the same?

Comment: add `-trace-ascii dump.txt` to the command line and check that file after you've run your command...

Comment: I get "== Info: Could not resolve host: "200905shwpkzwvw4coy""

Comment: ... which hints that you somehow got the argument to `--data` wrong (quote issues?) so that curl interpreted that sequence as the URL instead of post content.

Comment: and please drop `-X POST` it makes my head hurt.

Comment: @Daniel Stenberg Thank you. But what is beter? When i search on stackoverflow I find many examples woth this

Comment: And you'll find many comments from me saying remove it. Just remove it. It only causes problems on command lines like this. You don't need it. Drop it.

Comment: I think `-X POST` is implied by `--data`, but there's no problem being explicit about it! (The fact that I said "I think" is proof of that!)

Answer (score 1):

When interpolating, the value is split on whitespace.<sup>[1]</sup>

As such,

```sh
a='a b c'
prog $a
```

is equivalent to

```sh
prog 'a' 'b' 'c'
```

---

This splitting doesn't occur if the interpolation occurs inside of double-quotes.

As such,

```sh
a='a b c'
prog "$a"
```

is equivalent to

```sh
prog 'a b c'
```

---

Therefore, you need to change

```sh
$deleteValues
```

to

```sh
"$deleteValues"
```

---

1. To be precise, the `IFS` env var controls how the value is split. It's normally set such that splitting occurs on spaces, tabs and line feeds.